# why does align right apply only to first page menu? Also how to make column mandatory, and add decimal points and coma separators?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table, in which I want the amount column values to be **right aligned with two decimal points and comma separators**. Also, I need to make a **field mandatory** only if an amount has been entered. For instance, I want to make the date field mandatory when a value is entered in either debit or credit columns?

I started with one task, the right alignment. But it affects only the first part of the menu, and the second part onwards stays the same. Don't know where I go wrong.

Quick help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

My code is,

````
                  var length=table.rows.length-1;
                   //alert(length1);
                     for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) { 
                      $("#sample1 tr:eq("+ r +") td:eq(5)").addClass('right');
                      $("#sample1 tr:eq("+ r +") td:eq(4)").addClass('right');
                  } ```
````

Comment: field mandatory,still !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the code for coma Separator, with decimal point...Just be sure of your form column number inside (td:eq()).

```
if(cr!=""){
var num=parseFloat(cr).toFixed(3);
num=numberSeparator(num);
($("#sample1 tr:eq("+ index +") td:eq(5)").text(num));
}else{
$("#credit"+index).text('0.000');
}
***********************************************************************************

var commaCounter = 10;
                                function numberSeparator(Number) {
                                    Number += '';
                                    for (var i = 0; i < commaCounter; i++) {
                                        Number = Number.replace(',', '');
                                    }
                                    x = Number.split('.');
                                    y = x[0];
                                    z = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
                                    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
                                    while (rgx.test(y)) {
                                        y = y.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
                                    }
                                    commaCounter++;
                                    return y + z;
                                }
                                // Set Currency Separator to input fields
                                $('.number-separator').on('input', function (e) {
                                    if (/^-?\d*[,.]?(\d{0,3},)*(\d{3},)?\d{0,3}$/.test(e.originalEvent.data)) {
                                        e.target.value = numberSeparator(e.target.value);
                                    } else {
                                        e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.value.length - 1);
                                    }
                                });
                                // Set Currency Separator to input fields
                                $('.number-separator').on('td', function (e) {
                                    if (/^-?\d*[,.]?(\d{0,3},)*(\d{3},)?\d{0,3}$/.test(e.originalEvent.data)) {
                                        e.target.value = numberSeparator(e.target.value);
                                    } else {
                                        e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.value.length - 1);
                                    }
                                });
                                $(document).on('input', '.number-separator', function (e) {
                                    if (/^-?\d*[,.]?(\d{0,3},)*(\d{3},)?\d{0,3}$/.test(e.originalEvent.data)) {
                                        e.target.value = numberSeparator(e.target.value);
                                        } else {
                                            e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.value.length - 1);
                                        }
                                    });
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the code for right align...Here I am using two targets in one columnDefs
(Just to show, how to do two targets in one columnDefs, which was also my concern). Can also give one target instead.

```
"columnDefs": [
                                    {
                                        "targets": [6 ],
                                        "class": 'hidden',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "targets": [4,5],
                                        "class": 'right',
                                    } 
                                    ],
```